# Log energy and Shannon entropy?

Tags: image-processing, wavelet

For best tree decomposition using wavelet packets, i have tried both Shannon and log energy entropy functions. I noticed that log energy leads to images with higher PSNR values. Could you please help me explaining the reason?

- The Matlab expression for the two cases is as following: [Arec,bitstream,PSNR,MSE,D,Drec,s,p_stream]=spiht_wpackets('lena256.bmp',1,'CDF_9x7',5,4,'greedy','shannon'); [Arec,bitstream,PSNR,MSE,D,Drec,s,p_stream]=spiht_wpackets('lena256.bmp',1,'CDF_9x7',5,4,'greedy','logenergy');

Lena256 (image with size 256*256)

Comment: do you have example pictures?

Comment: For Lena image, Shannon entropy results in 33.3474 PSNR, and 37.0216 PSNR for logarithm energy entropy.

Comment: wait. Are we talking about the same image, just two *different PSNR* definitions, or are we talking about two different reduced versions of the same image, being subjected to the *same PSNR* measurement method?

Comment: @  Marcus Müller For the same image, the same PSNR measurement method and the same bpp: the use of Shannon entropy achieved 33.3474 PSNR, and log energy achieved PSNR of 37.0216.

Comment: what is "use of shannon entropy", then? I'm confused. Can you add a description of what exactly you're doing to get these two values *to your question*, please?

Comment: Marcus Müller, The Matlab expression for the two cases is as following: [Arec,bitstream,PSNR,MSE,D,Drec,s,p_stream]=spiht_wpackets('lena256.bmp',1,'CDF_9x7',5,4,'greedy','shannon');                                       [Arec,bitstream,PSNR,MSE,D,Drec,s,p_stream]=spiht_wpackets('lena256.bmp',1,'CDF_9x7',5,4,'greedy','logenergy');

Comment: As said, please add that **to the question** instead of as comment. Also, the "lena256.bmp" is an important piece of information! You didn't mention it's quantized, and I presume that's what the "256" means!!! so, please, go ahead, **edit** your question and give as much background as feasible!